# How to get the same window between process "Safari" and application "Safari"?

Tags: applescript

I know that I can get id of windows of Safari by:

```
tell application "Safari" to set winId to id of first window
```

But I can not get id of window like:

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari" 
   set winId to id of first window
end tell
```

Is there any property of window  can be used to identity the same window between *tell process "Safari"* and *tell application "Safari"*?

Comment: You could compare the results of `tell application "Safari" to get properties of window 1` and `tell application "System Events" to get properties of window 1 of process "Safari"` to see what's in common! I guess the question is, why do you need to use System Events and not just talk directly to Safari?

Comment: I want to get some properties of attributes which can only get in tell app "System Events" to tell process, and get the same window id  in tell application "Safari" as an input of some function.And I tried name of the window, but there may  have the  same name of windows. @user3439894